# DiscordJS: How pick random user in current channel that is online?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

In Discord.js version 12 I use `message.channel.members.random().toString()` to get a random users name in the current channel. But I only want this for members who have the status "Online" in the **current** channel. Not members with presence status dnd, idle or offline.

All users who are online can be queried as follows, for the whole server (what I do not want) and pick a random username for mention.
`message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status == 'online').random().toString()`

**message.channel.members** have no information about presence status (online,offline,dnd,idle).

> [{"guildID":"12...89","joinedTimestamp":12...89,"lastMessageChannelID":null,"premiumSinceTimestamp":null,"deleted":false,"nickname":null,"userID":"12...89","displayName":"Nickname"}]

How can I get the name(mention) of a randomly selected member with presence status "online" in the **current** channel?

Source https://discordjs.guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by filtering the status of the users **that can view the channel**.

```
message.channel.members.filter(member => member.presence.status == 'online').random()
```

`channel.members` has the type of `Collection<Snowflake, GuildMember>`, so you can access the presence data inside `GuildMember`.

Comment: Shame on me, I tried it with "cache" message.channel.members.cache.filter(..) and failed. The solution was so close. ;)